# Is ${R /I} \cong {{\mathbb Z} /{9\mathbb Z}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-isomorphism

If $$R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt2] = \{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b \in \mathbb Z\}\\I = \{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b \in 3\mathbb Z\}$$

Is ${R /I} \cong {{\mathbb Z} /{9\mathbb Z}}$?

Comment: In fact, $R/I$ is a field with $9$ elements.

Comment: @user26857:  I plead lack of early morning clarity!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Note that $1 + 1 + 1 = 0$ in $R/I$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$. (In fact, $R/I$ is the field with 9 elements).

Comment: So right, sorry for the confusion.